# Создание последовательных закладок при скролле

Tags: html, jquery

Задача: когда мы скроллим страницу, то при достижении тэга h1 верха страницы, слева добавляется закладка с текстом этого тэга. Если мы скроллим дальше и достигаем следующего тега h1, то его текст добавляется уже к первому текст. И так далее. Когда скроллим обратно, добавленные элементы последовательно удаляются. 
[Codepеn](http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/BKQdwO) и сам код:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
 $('h2').each(function(i){
  var elementOnTop = $(this).offset().top,
        winSize = $(window).scrollTop(),
            id = $(this).attr('id'),
      title = $(this).text(),
      textId = 'text-' + id + i++

    if (winSize > elementOnTop) {
    $('.marks').append("<div id='"+ textId +"'>" + title + "</div>");
   console.log('true!')
  } else {
            if ($('.marks div').has('#'+textId)) {
             $('#'+textId).remove();

                }
  }
 })
});
```

Проблема в том, что нужный элемент append'ится каждый раз при скролле. Как сделать, чтобы это происходило последовательно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заменяем одну вашу строку

```
$('.marks').append("<div id='" + textId + "'>" + title + "</div>");
```

на

```
if ($('.marks div:contains('+ title + ')').length == 0) {
    $('.marks').append("<div id='" + textId + "'>" + title + "</div>");
}
```

Работает http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNdGvj

Эта строка неверная, так как `id` вы извлекаете при помощи `this` в контексте `h2`, но у заголовка нет `id`, поэтому приходит `undefined`.

```
textId = 'text-' + id + i++
```

Comment: Да, вижу... Проблему. Спасибо. Сейчас разгребу весь мусор. )